# Installing the latest texlive via command line on ubuntu 18.04 LTS virtual machine

Tags: 18.04, apt, package-management, latex, texlive

Today, I installed texlive by `sudo apt-get install texlive-full`. 
Then I found out that's not the latest version, so I uninstalled it.

I have read some threads related to it, but I am getting more confused as I am a very beginner level user of ubuntu. 
Kindly provide me step by step commands through which I can install the latest texlive 2020 from terminal.

Comment: Just curious - why do you think you need latest TeXLive? This software is very stable, so you can stick with 2018. Even JonathonF provides [packaged 2019](https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/texlive-2019).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software)

Comment: @N0rbert, no, I was thinking I should install the latest texlive. so I just wanna know what do I need to run on my terminal to install the latest one.

Comment: Also see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95373/78560

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You will get TeXLive 2019 on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS by using [JonathonF PPA](https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/texlive-2019):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/texlive-2019
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install texlive
```

Another option is to install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and use TeXLive 2020 from it.

---

As usual this PPA may be removed by the commands below:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:jonathonf/texlive-2019
```

Comment: after running `sudo apt-get install texlive-full` it is showing:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/8N2pp7cSsK/

Comment: This means that PPA does not provide really full package. You have to decide which languages and styles do you really need and install only these packages. Do you have particular reason to not to use TeXLive 2018?

Comment: yeah, I think I only need English, but I am not sure about styles...
Please tell me which ones should I install and how I can do it.

Comment: It depends on the document templates. I would recommend you start from some example and then install optional stuff on-the-go.

Comment: After completing the installation of texlive, I am facing problem in compiling biblatex. 
It says:

`Error: Could not start the command: biber `  

Can you kindly tell me what I should I do?

Comment: Then you need to install it by `sudo apt-get install biber`.

Comment: but, when I run `sudo apt-get install biber`, it shows:
  `texlive-bibtex-extra` will be REMOVED. 
but I need it too for using `biblatex` package! Isn't it?

Comment: If you need biber, then agree with this prompt. I would suggest to stay with TeXLive from official repositories to get more reproducible results. This is why I say about TeXLive from official repositories. I do not find any reason to use latest. 2018 is stable.

Comment: The dummy pictures (for example: `\includegraphics{example-image-plain}` ) were not working in texlive 2018. That's one of the reasons I was told to use the latest version.

Comment: I'm not a LaTeX professional, but adding `\usepackage{graphicx}` to the preamble will support this syntax. It works even on 16.04 LTS with TeXLive 2015.

Comment: Okay, let me check again with installing TeXLive 2018.