# Problem due to package dependency between `texlive-bibtex-extra` and `biber` in TeXLive 2019 on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS virtual machine

Tags: 18.04, package-management, latex, texlive

I am a beginner level user of Ubuntu (18.04 LTS virtual machine). I have [installed the TeXLive 2019](https://askubuntu.com/a/1227879/947071) via command line:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/texlive-2019
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install texlive
```

Now, I need the `\usepackage{biblatex}` which lives in the TeXLive package `texlive-bibtex-extra`. Also, I need another TeXLive package `biber`. 
But when I come to install `biber`, it's asking to uninstall `texlive-bibtex-extra`. 
What can I do now?

Comment: Though it's not helping me, but seems it's the same issue with the previous versions of Ubuntu and TeXLive:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/761985/textlive-bibtex-extra-and-biber-conflict

Comment: I would recommend to ask *jonathonf* directly using [special contact form on launchpad](https://launchpad.net/%7Ejonathonf/+contactuser) as he is responsive about packaging texlive in his PPA.

Comment: @N0rbert, okay, let's see. I have emailed him,

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is probably better handled by the PPA author, as [commented by @N0orbert](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1228524/problem-due-to-package-dependency-between-texlive-bibtex-extra-and-biber-in/1228573#comment2067526_1228524). I offer an alternate option here.

Another possibility is to install a ["portable" TeXLive instance](https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#tlportable) in a directory under your home (I have several TeXLive instances installed in my system; I use them to check my package under several version of the main packages --- TeX/LaTeX is a *very* active community, and 3 years of development is a lot of changes). The advantage is that your installation is in parallel to the system one, the disadvantage is that it is not easily integrated in the desktop (you have to use a lot of command line instruction [note 1]).

Do everything as a normal user, so you will not touch the standard installation.

Basically you follow the [instructions to acquire a network TeXLive installation](https://tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html).

1. download the TeXLive network installer
2. follow the instruction to install the network version of TeXLive https://tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html --- be sure to select a "portable installation" under a personal directory, like `$HOME/texlive2020` or similar.
3. You now have to change your PATH to find the new directories before the system ones. I use [this script from AlexG](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/52535330#52535330) to have a shell using the portable one.

Notice that this is a sort-of advanced setup, so you need to understand things as the environment variables, startup scripts, `PATH` and similar thing, otherwise do not do it.

The downside is that you will need an extra 6-8 Gbyte for every TeXLive version you have (more if you do not disable backups[note 2]) and all of this will need to be downloaded from your internet link.

*[note 1]* Well, you can change your startup scripts to add the new directories in front of the standard ones. It will be only for your user and I never did it, so I do not guarantee that it will work ok.

*[note 2]* You have to keep your new repository up-to-date, running `tlmgr update --all --self` (with the correct `PATH`!) manually from time to time. That will keep old package versions as backups; [you can remove them/avoid them if you want](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172626/backups-for-tlpkg-during-tlmgr-update), but by default it will do backups.

Comment: Thank you!
But I guess the procedure is quite advanced for me as a beginner level user. 
I have emailed the PPA author, thinking of waiting to get a reply from him.

Comment: And just an another option I forgot before - we can use special Docker container with any texlive version inside - see  https://hub.docker.com/r/raabf/texstudio-versions .

Comment: @N0rbert --- really interesting! Thank you.

Comment: Thank you guys!
I got a reply from the PPA author. He has [updated the package `biber`](https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/texlive-2019). My problem is solved now.